# Get photos only taken by iPhone Camera using ALAssetLibray

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, alasset

I am using ALAssetLibrary  to access camera roll. But it is getting all images, like what's App images, Facebook Image etc.

My code like this:

```
[_library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if (asset) {
               //Getting photos here 
        }];
    }     } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed.");
}];
```

Is there any way to get only Camera capture photos using ALAssetLibrary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between camera captured photos and WhatsApp images is the EXIF Data.

You can read it out with

```
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
NSDictionary *meta = [representation metadata];
```

or in Swift:

```
var representation = asset.defaultRepresentation()
var meta = representation.metadata()
```

This returns the following:

```
{TIFF}: {
    DateTime = "2014:04:01 20:33:59";
    Make = Apple;
    Model = "iPhone 5";
    Orientation = 3;
    ResolutionUnit = 2;
    Software = "7.1";
    XResolution = 72;
    YResolution = 72;
}, PixelWidth: 3264]
```

So you can check if Make is Apple, for WhatsApp images it is empty:

```
if([metaData["{TIFF}"]["Make"] isEqualToString: @"Apple"])
```

or in Swift:

```
if metaData["{TIFF}"]!["Make"] == "Apple"
```

Comment: Yes, I already implemented it. Any way thanks for making answer.